# How can I play online radio streaming with AudioService Plugin in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to play an online radio stream whose duration is unknown. (actually it's infinity!) But when I don't set the duration for this MediaItem in my MediaItems list, the audio service doesn't play this radio stream URL correctly!
So, how can I play this kind of sounds whose duration is unknown?

Comment: Can you provide some code related to your issue?